# Corrupt /tmp directory

Tags: tmp

My `/tmp` directory got corrupted. Things got scary for a while and I was unable to boot :-(. I have now got myself back to a working system by renaming the corrupt `/tmp` to `/tmp.old`, and creating a new `/tmp`:

```
drwxrwxrwt   6 root root       4096 Nov 29 13:44 tmp
drwxrwxrwt   4 root root 1013628928 Nov 29 13:49 tmp.old
```

I forced an fsck at reboot, and I expected that might fix things. It seemed to go ok, but if I attempt to look at or remove `/tmp.old`, `ls` or `rm` commands just hang and don't return any thing. How do I get rid of `/tmp.old` and make sure there are no other problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be a little different to what I was expecting. After I asked this question my `/tmp` directory "corrupted" two more times.

I finally figured out that actually it wasn't corrupt at all. It was just full of an **enormous** number of files (symlinks actually). So full in fact that `ls` would hang for a considerable time (over a minute) whilst it was processing the index before it would start doing anything. My system wouldn't boot because part of the start up process is to clear out `/tmp`, and it was getting stuck at this point. I never got the `rm` command to return at all even after waiting for a very long period of time. After doing some online research I eventually came across this command:

```
cd /tmp
sudo find . ! -path . -delete
```

This seemed to work faster and only took an hour or so!!

That sorted out the `/tmp` directory. The reason it was filling up was to do with printing. If I attempted to print something then that triggered the problem (although this wasn't immediately obvious as it took a while for `/tmp` to fill up). However looking at the symlinks that were being created, I noticed that they were all pointing at a ppd file for my printer. I deleted and reinstalled my printer using the hp-setup program (it's an HP printer) - but that didn't solve the problem. However deleting and manually setting up the printer without using hp-setup did. Not sure if this is a problem with hp-setup, my printer driver or cups...but it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Live boot into Ubuntu and remove it